# Setting up post-receive hook for bare repo

Tags: git, github, githooks

I have a bare repo set up in my ubuntu server.

After I push to my bare git repo to the server:

```
$ git push origin master
```

I want the contents of my non bare repo to be updated with the latest push as shown where the non bare repo is my actual work directory named workfiles.

```
$ cd /central/workfiles
$ git pull
$ exit
```

I have heard about the post-receive hook but do not know how to set up the same.
How can i achieve the same.

Answer (score 13):

I prefer specifying the working tree and git directory instead of relying on a cd:

```
/bare/repo.git/hooks/post-receive

#!/bin/sh
GIT_WORK_TREE=/central/workfiles GIT_DIR=/central/workfiles/.git git pull origin master
exit
```

As [commented below](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14453411/setting-up-post-receive-hook-for-bare-repo/14453711?noredirect=1#comment45159682_14453711) by [ChrisV](https://stackoverflow.com/users/342943/chrisv), you can also rely one a `git checkout` instead of a `git pull`

> I believe `git checkout -f` is safer than `git pull`, as the merge which is part of the pull has the potential to make things messy if manual fixups should be needed.

But that means `/central/workfiles` is *not* a "non-bare" git repo. It is just a folder where you checkout the content of the bare repo `/bare/repo.git`.
See [Brian Thomas](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1091853/brian-thomas)'s [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24027870/6309) for an example of that approach.

That would not fit the OP specification.

Comment: Should I just create the files from the contents you have given.It appears to me that it is in a single line.

Comment: @david.colais 3 lines: the bin/sh, one line for the pull, and one line for `exit` (although that `exit` line isn't really needed)

Comment: @david.colais so again, the pull itself is one line with two environment variables set: `GIT_WORK_TREE=/central/workfiles GIT_DIR=/central/workfiles/.git git pull origin master`

Comment: Late addition: I believe `git checkout -f` is safer than `git pull`, as the merge which is part of the pull has the potential to make things messy if manual fixups should be needed...

Comment: @ChrisV indeed. I have included your comment in the answer for more visibility.

Comment: Does `git checkout -f` pull the latest changes from the remote?

Comment: @Markasoftware You are right, it would *not*. I have amended the answer to make clear that a checkout would only work if the destination is *not* a git repo (just a folder you update)

Answer (score 6):

i use the post receive hook like this

```
#.git/hooks/post-receive

#!/bin/sh
GIT_WORK_TREE=/srv/http/sitedir/ git checkout -f
```

yes, make sure to make it executable.

Comment: is that the tactics @VonC ?  to add the snippet from someone else after theh answer to get the more recent datea, and all the votes? lol.  i gotta figure out how to get more points around here.  can you remove the code snippet  that duplicated my answer here plesae if possible and just replace that with see `@Brian Thomas` please, so i can get a few points on that?  Im trying to keep things fair and earn some rights on overflow, spotted this.... Thanks for any cooperation. Regards,. ..wait, i just thought of something, was that you that gave me the point?  if so, disregard, if no please do :-)

Answer (score 4):

I'd go with something like

```
#!/bin/sh

cd /central/workfiles
git pull
exit
```

Save the above script as `post-receive` and place it in the `hooks/` directory of your bare repo.

Bottom line don't forget to make it executable

```
chmod +x post-receive
```

Comment: I created a new file as post-receive but after I push to bare repo no changes get reflected in the non-bare repo which is my work dir

Comment: This will work only if GIT_DIR is set to ".git", otherwise you will get a bug