# Empty folder when pushing from local to remote

Tags: git, visual-studio-code

I have a project inside of `VS Code` which uses git locally and everything is commited / up to date.

Now I want to push all that to my server so I can update files on the server while working locally.

I've set up my git repo on my server and connected from vs code project terminal, however when I do a push it says that everything is "up to date", and the folder on the server is empty, it contains just the `.git` folder.

I want to transfer all my project files to the folder on the server, how do I do that?

Right now I am doing:

```
git push origin --all
```

And I get `Everything is up to date`

I also try doing:

```
git add.
git commit -m "commit message"
```

But I get

```
on branch master
Your branch is up to date with 'origin/master'.

nothing to commit, working tree clean
```

How can I send all my local git files to my server git repo?

Comment: Please write the output for git status, also i would like to confirm that git add. You are adding space between add and dot

Comment: Also please confirm that command will print your remote git url,      git remote show origin

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In addition of `git status` and `git remote -v,` don't forget that you would generally push to a [*bare* repository](https://stackoverflow.com/q/5540883/6309).

Meaning: the remote target should only have a `.git` folder with the compressed files received  from your local workstation.

You would not see any files there (beside the ones from the Git referential).

Comment: You are right, I've created a new empty project on my machine and cloned the repo there and I got all the files, so it is as you say, However I do actually want to see and use the files on my remote server, how can that be achieved?

Comment: Got it, By simply cloning it into another directory, thanks for helping me understand.

Comment: @jukenduit Yes, cloning, or setting up a post-receive hook which can make the clone/update for you: https://stackoverflow.com/a/14453711/6309

Answer (score 0):

Let's try this from the VSCode terminal.

1) Change the current working directory to your local repository (your
    project directory).

2) Stage the file for commit to your local repository.

```
git add .
# Adds the file to your local repository and stages it for commit.
```

3) Commit the file that you've staged in your local repository.

```
git commit -m "Your commit message here"
# Commits the tracked changes and prepares them to be pushed to a remote repository.
```

4) Push the changes in your local repository to the repository hosted on remote server (Example: GitHub).

```
git push origin master
# Pushes the changes in your local repository up to the remote repository you specified as the origin
```