# Terminate EC2 instance using command line API

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, ec2-ami, ec2-api-tools

I am having AWS EC2 instance and I am using it by putty.

I have also downloaded the EC2 command line API to that ec2 instance.

Now i want to terminate EC2 instance within same EC2 instance using EC2 command line API.

How can i terminate EC2 instance ?

Answer (score 3):

I think you are looking for `ec2-terminate-instances` command part of ec2-api-tools, check out [here](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/CommandLineReference/ApiReference-cmd-TerminateInstances.html)

```
PROMPT> ec2-terminate-instances <intance_id>
```

Answers for the question here [How can I kill all my EC2 instances from the command line?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/638352/how-can-i-kill-all-my-ec2-instances-from-the-command-line) can also help you

Comment: Yes i am looking for terminating instance but in this case, i have to give instance id.

I am not looking for this.

What i want is, when i am using instance via putty, through same command line i want to terminate the same instance not all other.

Like what we do 'init 0' in linux and 'shutdown -s' in windows.

Comment: Ok i got you, you should try `sudo halt` after SSHing to your instance.. see if it works

Comment: If the instance is set to terminate on user shutdown, then all you have to do is shut it down. This is a flag that can be changed between stop and terminate.

Comment: You can also retrieve the instance_id from within any EC2 instance (specific to the server you are in at any given moment, you can get any info for that box) from the internal instance metadata: 
http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/AESDG-chapter-instancedata.html

In your case you could just issue a wget or curl or GET to:
http://169.254.169.254/latest/meta-data/instance-id