# How to protect EC2 instance from immediate termination?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2

EC2 is designed to make it very easy to spin up instances and terminate them at will. Is there a way to add an additional protection to an EC2 (e.g. password protect, or even an additional confirmation) such that the typical means of instance termination (through the browser, [cli](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/userguide/cli-services-ec2-instances.html), or library like [boto3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/638352/how-can-i-kill-all-my-ec2-instances-from-the-command-line)) would require an extra step to be followed (such as a confirmation prompt or 'type the name of this instance' along the lines of the technique used by github when deleting a repository)?

Comment: Can you give more background around why you need this feature?  A typical solution would be to only give admin credentials/access to those users who are well trained on AWS and can be trusted with such permissions.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen this morning I terminated a bunch of instances (about 6) and I didn't realise that there was one additional (important) instance selected that should't have been, so it got terminated too. I'm just after a simple way to prevent this type of mishap

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen in other words, purely to protect against carelessness/accidents :-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a feature called "Termination Protection" that you can enable in important instances:

[image]

Then if you attempt to terminate one of them, you'll get this message, and the "Terminate" button won't be enabled:

[image]

More information about that feature [here](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/terminating-instances.html#Using_ChangingDisableAPITermination).